# Extracting and Mining PDF Data

Tags: etl

I have a pdf file (admission application). I want to read/search the pdf and extract terms with similar meaning and then convert this data into a DataFrame to save as a xlsm file. HELP!

Answer (score 4):

in my opinion, you have 4 possibilities:

- You may **treat the pdf directly** using [tabula](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py)
- You may **convert the pdf to text** using pdftotext, then parse text with python
- You may use an external tool, to **convert your pdf file to excel or CSV**, then use required python module to open the excel/CSV file.
- You may also **convert pdf to an image file**, then use any recent OCR software (which reconstruct table automatically from the picture) to get data

This answer comes from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533875/how-to-extract-table-as-text-from-the-pdf-using-python/53050405

Your question is near similar to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927880/extracting-tables-from-a-pdf
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591426/extract-table-from-a-pdf
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125178/how-to-scrape-tables-in-thousands-of-pdf-files
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868541/pdf-data-and-table-scraping-to-excel
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217194/extracting-table-contents-from-a-collection-of-pdf-files/26110587#26110587

Regards